# Add Column to CSV file Using Other CSV file

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, multiple-columns

I am working with two CSV files. One holds the name of users and the other one holds their corresponding email address. What I want to do is to combine them both so that users is column 1 and email is column 2 and output it to one file. So far, I've managed to add a second column from the email csv file to the user csv file, but with blank row data. Below is the code that I am using:

```
$emailCol= import-csv "C:\files\temp\emailOnly.csv" | Select-Object -skip 1
$emailArr=@{}
$i=0

$nameCol = import-csv "C:\files\temp\nameOnly.csv"

foreach ($item in $emailCol){
                             $nameCol | Select *, @{
                                                    Name="email";Expression= 
                                                    {$emailArr[$i]}
                                                    } | Export-Csv -path 
                             C:\files\temp\revised.csv -NoTypeInformation
                             }
```

Updated: Below is what worked for me. Thanks BenH!

```
function combineData    {
                        #This function will combine the user CSV file and 
                        #email CSV file into a single file

                        $emailCol = Get-Content "C:\files\temp\emailOnly.csv" 
                        | Select-Object -skip 1
                        $nameCol = Get-Content "C:\files\temp\nameOnly.csv" | 
                        Select-Object -skip 1

                        # Max function to find the larger count of the two 
                        #csvs to use as the boundary for the counter.
                        $count = [math]::Max($emailCol.count,$nameCol.count)

                        $CombinedArray = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++)  {
                                                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                                                    fullName = $nameCol[$i]
                                                    email = $emailCol[$i]
                                                                     }
                                                                            }

                        $CombinedArray | Export-Csv C:\files\temp\revised.csv 
                        -NoTypeInformation

                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [for loop](https://ss64.com/ps/for.html) would be better suited for your loop. Then use the counter as the index for each of the arrays to build your new object.

```
$emailCol = Get-Content "C:\files\temp\emailOnly.csv" | Select-Object -Skip 2
$nameCol = Get-Content "C:\files\temp\nameOnly.csv" | Select-Object -Skip 1

# Max function to find the larger count of the two csvs to use as the boundary for the counter.
$count = [math]::Max($emailCol.count,$nameCol.count)
$CombinedArray = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $nameCol[$i]
        Email = $emailCol[$i]
    }
}
$CombinedArray | Export-Csv C:\files\temp\revised.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer edited to use `Get-Content` with an extra skip added to skip the header line in order to handle blank lines.

Comment: Great! This adds more progress! However, the objects in each row data display this way:

Name                                         Email
@{displayName=Administrator} @{email=Snookie@NJ.org}


Also, one of the users do no have an email assigned, so they would need to be skipped. However, the code you've causes the email row to skip the blank line, which throws off the rest of the users corresponding email.

Comment: @LilithMae Maybe it's better show the parts of samples your CSV files first and explain all nuances what you actually want?

Comment: @LilithMae Answer updated, to get rid of the `@{email=` you would use the property that matched the header in your csv. e.g. `Name = $nameCol.DisplayName[$i]` However just using `Get-Content` solves your blank line issue as well.

Comment: @BenH This works out great! THanks for all your help :) While I was awaiting your response I realized that there were some scripts I ran previously that caused blank rows to be removed. After I modified that script, then this on worked. I've updated my question with what worked for me :) Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent some additional questions about this theme let me show you alternative approach. If your both CSV files have same number of lines and each line of the first file corresponds to the first line of the second file and etc. then you can do next. For example, users.csv:

```
User
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
```

and email.csv:

```
Email
mail1@gmail.com
mail2@gmail.com
mail3@gmail.com

mail5@gmail.com
```

Our purpose:

```
"User","Email"
"Name1","mail1@gmail.com"
"Name2","mail2@gmail.com"
"Name3","mail3@gmail.com"
"Name4",
"Name5","mail5@gmail.com"
```

What we do?

```
$c1 = 'C:\path\to\user.csv'
$c2 = 'C:\path\to\email.csv'
[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip(
  (Get-Content $c1), (Get-Content $c2),[Func[Object, Object, Object[]]]{$args -join ','}
) | ConvertFrom-Csv | Export-Csv C:\path\to\output.csv
```

If our purpose is:

```
"User","Email"
"Name1","mail1@gmail.com"
"Name2","mail2@gmail.com"
"Name3","mail3@gmail.com"
"Name5","mail5@gmail.com"
```

then:

```
$c1 = 'C:\path\to\user.csv'
$c2 = 'C:\path\to\email.csv'
([Linq.Enumerable]::Zip(
  (Get-Content $c1), (Get-Content $c2),[Func[Object, Object, Object[]]]{$args -join ','}
) | ConvertFrom-Csv).Where{$_.Email} | Export-Csv C:\path\to\output.csv
```

Hope this helps you in the future.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the tips @greg!

Comment: Great, I like Linq-Adaptions in PS